# Compiling std::transforms with argument atan2/pow fails with clang (but works with gcc)

Tags: xcode, c++11, gcc, clang++

There seem to be some difference in how template parameters are resolved for clang and gcc. Or maybe clang does not consider `atan2` and `pow` binary operations but gcc does.

The code sample below does not make much sense on its own but recreates the issue in a minimal fashion:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

#define TRANSFORM_MACRO(op,func)                                          \
    template<class T>                                                     \
    std::vector<T> &trans_##op(const std::vector<T> &a, const std::vector<T> &b, std::vector<T> &dst) { \
      std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), dst.begin(), func);   \
      return dst;                                                         \
    }                                                                     \
    template std::vector<float> &trans_##op(const std::vector<float>&, const std::vector<float>&, std::vector<float>&);     \
    template std::vector<double> &trans_##op(const std::vector<double>&, const std::vector<double>&, std::vector<double>&);

TRANSFORM_MACRO(arctan2, ::atan2)

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this with GCC (5.4 Ubuntu; 6.0 OSX Sierra) works fine. Using clang (900.0.37) returns the following error:

```
/Users/alneuman/CLionProjects/temptest/main.cpp:15:1: error: no matching function for call to 'transform'
TRANSFORM_MACRO(arctan2, atan2)
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/.../CLionProjects/temptest/main.cpp:9:7: note: expanded from macro 'TRANSFORM_MACRO'
      std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), dst.begin(), func);       \
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/.../CLionProjects/temptest/main.cpp:15:1: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'trans_arctan2<float>' requested here
/Users/.../CLionProjects/temptest/main.cpp:12:34: note: expanded from macro 'TRANSFORM_MACRO'
    template std::vector<float> &trans_##op(const std::vector<float>&, const std::vector<float>&, std::vector<float>&);     \
                                 ^
<scratch space>:22:1: note: expanded from here
trans_arctan2
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:1932:1: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_BinaryOperation'
transform(_InputIterator1 __first1, _InputIterator1 __last1, _InputIterator2 __first2,
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:1922:1: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 4 arguments, but 5 were provided
transform(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _OutputIterator __result, _UnaryOperation __op)
```

The problem seems to be that GCC uses the builtin versions of `atan2` and `pow` which only have one definition and therefore do not need specification. Clang seems to fall back to std::atan2/pow which have multiple definitions. Clang also has a `__builtin_atan2` but this cannot be used with `std::transform` as it has to be called directly (considering the compiler output).

Comment: `using std::atan2;` reproduces the issue with gcc. atan2 is overloaded, you need to specify which overload you want.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: I think this points me in the right direction. In the original code, `std::transform` is part of a macro (I updated the example accordingly). If I cast the function pointer of func in the template like `static_cast<T(*)(T, T)>(func)` the code works for clang but not for gcc. GCC complains about `invalid static_cast from type 'double(double, double)' to type 'float (*)(float, float)'`. Looks like GCC does not know the float version of atan2, does it.

Comment: Replace atan2 with `std::atan2` so gcc knows the float version. (or `atan2f`, but then you should include `<math.h>` instead)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MarcGlisse I guess I figured out what causes the different behaviour for Clang and GCC. The `::` notation asks to look for a function in the global namespace. GCC has `atan2` [builtin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) with a `double` signature in the global namespace but Clang does not. The `std` [version](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan2) Clang is using features a `double` and a `float` signature. Therefore, when `std::atan2` is being used, the compiler requires more specific information which overload should be used as `std::atan2` has (at least) three overloads: `float`, `double` and `long double`. This can be achieved with a static cast. The `float` cast obviously fails when GCC's built version is used since `double` to `float` cannot be casted statically.

I went for `TRANSFORM_MACRO(arctan2, static_cast<T(*)(T, T)>(std::atan2))` which resolves the ambiguity in the macro and also makes GCC and Clang use the same version of atan2.